# Navigate files with VisualStudio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ide

I am currently developing with VisualStudio 2008. I find it increasingly difficult to find files when the number of files and projects increase. The situation become so bad that I literally have to spend 10-20 seconds to find code I want to work on when switch between files. Sounds like not a lot of time, but this can be very annoying because it breaks the "coding flow".

I believe this is a general problem with all IDEs. But I still find it easier to work with Eclipse. One particular example is that in Eclipse, I could apply some key shortcut to find implementations defined in an Interface.(I have forgotten which key shortcut though, after not working with it for about 1 year.) Another example is that in VS 2008, rightclick->Find all references will find all occurrences containing the ***selected text***(***Update: This accusation is incorrect. Thanks for pointing it out***); while similar operation in Eclipse will find all occurrences where the selected class/variable are ***referenced***. Personally, I find the Eclipse way is better for file navigation.

This could be due to my inexperience with VS IDE. So, I am looking for suggestions to improve the file navigation experience so that I can get some more time for actual coding.

I have used the navigate buttons but they are only useful for small number of files.
Thanks.

Comment: This is not true: `rightclick->Find all references will find all occurrences containing the selected text;`

Comment: My bad. Just played with this operation and you are absolutely right. I do apology for this misinformation.

Comment: Mistake != misinformation.   Misinformation is like when the government tells us it will provide us better health care for fewer dollars.  Mistakes are like when we believe them ;)

Comment: OK, I didn't mean to mis-inform you. This is a "human error" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree wholeheartedly about ReSharper. If you don't want a "paid" solution though, a useful Visual Studio shortcut is

<kbd>CTRL + ,</kbd>

it gives a list of recently edited files.

[CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) is a free alternative to ReSharper which you might find useful too.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded CodeRush and it did help a LOT.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Jetbrains Resharper.  Ctrl N or Ctrl Shift N.  To jump quickly to files by type name or by file name.  Also you can control Click Classes to navigate to them instantly.

I can't even work in visual studio without it anymore.  It virtually eliminates the need for the solution explorer

Comment: Employer wouldn't spend extra $ on add on software. So, this is not an option even though I am sure it will improve the experience.

Comment: Well, if it improves your performance, why don't YOU spend the money on it?  It's seriously not that expensive.  For $200 you can drastically reduce your job frustration...

Comment: In NorthAmerica and Europe. $200 is like 5-6 hrs of salary for an average programmer. However, in the place I work, $200 is half a month of work. So, I have to think twice before making this kind of purchases.

Answer (score 0):

[SamTools for Visual Studio 2005/2008](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/index.php?title=Tools:SamTools:Features) (and I have a build for 2010 if someone needs it). The particular feature that's handy here is the Solution File List.

- You can right click the tab of any open document and Find In Solution Explorer or Show In Windows Explorer
- You can right click in the Solution File List for the same
- Unlike other solutions to this problem, this is a properly docking tool pane so it fits in great. Ctrl+Alt+F places you in the Filter box with the current text selected, so it's very easy to work with.

Oh and it's free/GPL. :)

[Solution File List http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/images/8/88/SamTools_SlnFileList.png](http://wiki.pixelminegames.com/images/8/88/SamTools_SlnFileList.png)

Answer (score 0):

Dpack is also a free alternative with some nice file navigation shortcuts, but Resharper is the bomb.

BTW, they should have some more of this stuff in vs2010, which is in beta right now (I think)